# Text not showing up on site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some text to show up when variable `t = <100` but it's not working, I have no idea why :(

```js
var t = 100;
function tel(){ 
 t--;
 console.log(t);
return document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = t;
}
if (t < 97){
 document.getElementById('nba').innerHTML = ('Ja he');
}else {
 document.getElementById('nba').innerHTML = ('Blijf klikken')
}
if (t < 35){
 document.write("op de helft");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>madafaka</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

<p id="tel"></p>
<br>
<button id="lol" type="button" onclick="tel()">Klik!</button>

<p id="nba"></p>
<script src="jav.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like it's not printing the text and I have no idea why.

Comment: Nothing works when you use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) in an event handler.

Comment: Your `if`s are outside the `tel()`function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use you compare codes in your function= tel();

```js
var t = 100; 
function tel(){    
  t--;
  console.log(t);
  
  // compares
  if (t < 97){
    document.getElementById('nba').innerHTML = ('Ja he');
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById('nba').innerHTML = ('Blijf klikken')
  }
  if (t < 35){
    document.write("op de helft");
  }

  return document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = t;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 10% !important; }
```

```html
<button id="lol" type="button" onclick="tel()">Klik!</button>

<p id="nba"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are validation your code outside your `if(){} else{}` and returned the new value before the checks where done. Keep in mind your browser reads from top to bottom. And when the counter is below 35 your button will be replaced with "op de helft".